# Overflow Error code for Poisson Regression

Tags: python, dataframe, regression, shapes, poisson

I have encountered overflow error code when I execute the fit() function. May I know what have I done wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

X.head()
```

[Dataframe X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxWtQ.png)

```
X.shape
```

(40,14)

My dataframe for Y is

[Dataframe Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9q14.png)

```
Y.shape
```

(40,)

```
clf = linear_model.PoissonRegressor()
clf.fit(X,Y)
```

I have the following error code

[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M40u9.png)